# Wrap image with text

Tags: react-native

Is there a possibility to make the text and the image to look something like this:

[image: wrapped image with text]

The only difference is that I need to show the image in bottom right corner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure this out? You can nest `<Image>` within `<Text>` but im having vertical align issues on ios.